# Sculpt mode not working for blender newbie

Tags: sculpt

thanks for reading.

I'm a blender newbie. I downloaded the program just a few nights ago.
I'm trying to use the sculpt mode, but when I click (or use my wacom click) on the cube, it simply does nothing.

My cursor shows up as a blue circle on the side of the cube, and when I click, all I get is the "cancel" option in the bottom left. Nothing else.

It's not that my click isn't working - I can use "annotate" to draw just fine. But when I try to use any of the options within sculpt mode - draw, draw sharp, clay, clay script etc, none of them actually have any affect on the cube.

Any help hugely appreciated. Will attach screengrab.

Thank you.

Blender v3.4.1.
Apple iMac running MacOs Monterey[image]

Comment: You need to give topology to your object, otherwise you have nothing to sculpt, have you subdivided the object? Or enable the Dyntopo option, which will create topology under the brush

Comment: Or try the [voxel remesh](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/remesh.html). Press Shift+R to define the voxel size visually with a grid. Then press Ctrl+R to remesh (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/252931/107598). That's the shortcuts for the remesh tool. This question might help you also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/238582/107598. There is also the Quadriflow remesh (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/234835/107598).

Comment: Thanks so much people, I really appreciate your help with this. You sorted my issue.